# CSRF token missing or incorrect when i use react-native api post request. how can i send request without csrf

Tags: react-native, django-rest-framework, http-post

I want to send a rest-api post request from react-native, but it throws the error csrf token is missing or incorrect as shown in the image.
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/RwLlk.png).

this is my sample of code. and I send a post request for rest-framework.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Button, StyleSheet, Text, TextInput, View } from 'react-native';

const App = () => {
    const [email, SetEmail] = useState("");
    const [password1, SetPassword1] = useState("");
    const [password2, SetPassword2] = useState("");
    const [username, SetUsername] = useState("");
    const [country, SetCountry] = useState("");

    const data = {
        email: email,
        password1: password1,
        password2: password2,
        username: username,
        country: country

    }

    const login = async () => {
        const url = "https://someurl";

        let response = await fetch(url, {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                Accept: 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                Referer: url,
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(data)
        });
        response = await response.json();
        console.warn(response);
    }
    return (
        <View>
            <Text style={{ fontSize: 30, margin: 20 }}>Welcome to udiMagic</Text>
            <TextInput placeholder='Email' value={email} onChangeText={(text) => SetEmail(text)}></TextInput>
            <TextInput placeholder='Password' secureTextEntry={true} value={password1} onChangeText={(text) => SetPassword1(text)}></TextInput>
            <TextInput placeholder='Confirm Password' secureTextEntry={true} value={password2} onChangeText={(text) => SetPassword2(text)}></TextInput>
            <TextInput placeholder='Username' value={username} onChangeText={(text) => SetUsername(text)}></TextInput>
            <TextInput placeholder='Country' value={country} onChangeText={(text) => SetCountry(text)}></TextInput>
            <Button title="Login" color={'green'} onPress={login} />
        </View >
    );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Hi @Hemangi Savsani, I have tried the above code locally and it is working absolutely well if we are providing the correct body. There is nothing wrong with your react-native code. But sometimes the server of the endpoint `https://testudimagic.in/api/v1/auth/registration/` is throwing the csrf error in case of too many requests.

Comment: I tried with postman as well and the end point worked well for the first time. May be you are making too many API calls because of which it is throwing the error.